# choosing a specific button from a list of identical buttons

Tags: python-3.x, list, button, tkinter

I am making a battleships program, and after i created a list of identical buttons for a grid and inserting them all into one list, i want to be able to choose the button just clicked and delete it. How can i achieve this?

```
l = []
for i in range (100):

    b = Button(battleship.frame, height = 1, width = 3, command =  )
    l.append(b) 
    #this is a snippet of what i have now but i am not sure what to do.
```

I have tried using lambda to give each button something unique to make them all different but i don't think this helps me in selecting the specific button that was just clicked.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you just want to delete it from the grid, you can call `b.config(command=b.grid_forget)` (assume you use `.grid(...)` to layout the buttons) after you create the button.

Comment: Amazing this worked liked a dream thanks so much